# Jetpack compose factory functions

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm formatting an amount using Jetpack Compose and applying different TextStyles to the part after the comma and the part before the comma. Essentially, I'm creating a Composable function that returns an AnnotatedString. Is this usage correct? Is it OK for composable functions to return a value?

```
@Composable
fun formattedAmount(
    amount: Double,
    currencySymbol: String,
    minFractionDigits: Int = 2,
    maxFractionDigits: Int = 2,
    intPartTextStyle: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitleS2,
    fractionPartTextStyle: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitleS4,
    textColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.Gray900,
): AnnotatedString {

    val formatResult = AmountFormatter.format(
        amount,
        currencySymbol,
        minFractionDigits,
        maxFractionDigits,
        TLFormatter()
    )

    val formattedAmount = formatResult.formattedText
    val fractionSeparator = formatResult.fractionSeparator
    val splitAmount = formattedAmount.split(fractionSeparator)
    val intPart = splitAmount.firstOrNull()
    val fractionPart = if (splitAmount.size > 1) {
        splitAmount.last()
    } else null

    return buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(style = intPartTextStyle.copy(color = textColor).toSpanStyle()) {
            append(intPart)
        }
        withStyle(style = fractionPartTextStyle.copy(color = textColor).toSpanStyle()) {
            fractionPart?.let {
                append(fractionSeparator)
                append(it)
            }
            append(" $currencySymbol")
        }
    }
}


Text(
                text = buildAnnotatedString {
                    withStyle(
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.paragraphB4.toSpanStyle()
                    ) {
                        append(stringResource(R.string.your_available_balance))
                    }
                    withStyle(
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitleS4.toSpanStyle()
                    ) {
                        append(" ")
                        append(
                            formattedAmount(
                                amount = availableBalance,
                                currencySymbol = cryptoCurrencyCode,
                                minFractionDigits = minFractionDigits,
                                maxFractionDigits = maxFractionDigits
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
```

Is it OK for composable functions to return a value?